# Django Model Form Validation not validating

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hey I am busy with Django forms working on custom validation etc, so when I test whether this validation is working it does not work I tried watching videos so to know where I am going wrong but I personally do not see the flaw.

I did a password validation and it does not raise the validation error to me even when I write two different passwords.

**Code Below: models.py**

```
class UserAccounts(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    verify_password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def clean_password(self):

        passwd = self.cleaned_data_get('password')
        v_passwd = self.cleaned_data_get('verify_password')

        if passwd != v_passwd:
            raise ValidationError('Passwords do not match')

        return passwd
```

**Code Below: forms.py**

```
class UserAccountsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAccounts
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {

            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'First Name'}),

            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Last Name'}),

            'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Phone Number'}),

            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}),

            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Password'}),

            'verify_password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Verify Password'})

        }


    def clean_password(self):

        passwd = self.cleaned_data_get('password')
        v_passwd = self.cleaned_data_get('verify_password')

        if passwd != v_passwd:
            raise ValidationError('Passwords do not match')

        return passwd
```

Comment: the `clean_` methods belong on the Form class, not the Model

Comment: I had tried that before sending the ```clean``` method to models.py  because It was not raising any errors let me show you how I had done it I will edit the code in question

Comment: Why would you have a `password` and `verify_password` field on your model?

Comment: I am trying to make a registration form and registration forms normally have password field and a field to verify your password that is something I was trying to replicate there so to learn custom validation etc

Comment: Basically, this shouldn't be a `ModelForm`, because your form fields don't all correspond to model fields. It's clearly senseless to have a `verify_password` in your model, yet you need it in your form. Just write it as a standard `Form` - or use the one already [provided] by Django.

Comment: And I think it's worth noting that your approach, along with the technical problems noted above, appears to be storing user's passwords in plaintext in your database - which is a complete nono from a security point of view. One advantage of using Django's builtin models/forms for authentication is that you don't need to deal with hashing etc yourself.

Comment: Oh okay thanks would you recommend a book that I can read on Django Auth and many more? Thank so much for the point thought all noted